# How to recognize view movement on screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I'm working on an SDK for making tutorials. In this SDK I present a spotlight fragment in which I basically create a background canvas there I draw a darker background and a transparent rectangle that focuses on the desired view.

In some cases, this view might move. For example, the developer that uses my SDK creates a timed collapse of a view before the focused view which makes the focused view to move and as a result, my spotlight stays in the wrong location.

**The question is:** How can I recognize a view movement on the screen so I can update my spotlight fragment accordingly?

Comment: Do you have access to the view that is on focus?

Comment: @Krish yes I do, I have the view instance.

Comment: What about adding a LayoutChangelistener ?

Comment: @Krish but in this case, I will need to set LayoutChangeListener on the parent of the focused view, am I wrong? Or setting it on the focused view will inform me of the view movement?

Comment: Focused view will be fine from my understand.

Comment: @Krish, ok... let me test it and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147961/discussion-between-krish-and-emil-adz).

Comment: @Krish, tested LayoutChangeListener but it's not called on changing view location on screen. it's only called if the view bounds are changes which is not the case in my situation.

Comment: Have you got a solution?

Comment: @Krish, I found one solution, but I'm not 100% satisfied with it, I have provided it as an answer.

Comment: Did you check whether layout() callback is working with your scenario?

Comment: @Krish, could you please explain with more details, what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much better solution using the `OnPreDrawListener`:

```
private final ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener mPreDrawListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            if (!mAttached) {
                removePreDrawObserver(null);
                return true;
            }

            handleViewDraw();
            return true;
        }
    };
```

The `onPreDraw` method will be called each time the view is going to be redrawn.

Where `handleViewDraw` method will look like the follows:

```
private void handleViewDraw() {
        if (if mViewAnchor != null) {
            View view = mViewAnchor.get();
            if (null != view && view.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
                view.getLocationOnScreen(mTempLocation);

                if (mOldLocation == null) {
                    mOldLocation = new int[]{mTempLocation[0], mTempLocation[1]};
                }

                if (isTargetViewLocationChanged()) {
                    handleVisibleTargetViewLocationChange();
                }

                mOldLocation[0] = mTempLocation[0];
                mOldLocation[1] = mTempLocation[1];
            } else {
                mView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            mView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

private boolean isTargetViewLocationChanged() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Old: " + mOldLocation[1] + " ,TEMP: " + mTempLocation[1]);
        return mOldLocation[0] != mTempLocation[0] || mOldLocation[1] != mTempLocation[1];
    }
```

Using this method you will be notified only when the view moved, in difference with the 'active' solution that is supplied in the other answer this is a 'passive' solution which will run the `handleVisibleTargetViewLocationChange` method only when the view has actually moved.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I came up by now is the following 'active' solution, I'm running a `Task` every half a second that checks the `LocationOnScreen` of the target view. and if the target view changes it's coordinates I update the fragment. This solution works but I'm still looking for a 'passive' solution that updates me on the location changes instead of testing it every half a second:

```
  @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final View targetView = mDrawDataPojo.getWalkthroughMetaPojo().getTargetView().getView();
    if (targetView != null) {
        targetView.getLocationOnScreen(mOriginalLocationOnScreen);
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TargetViewChangeListener(), 0, 500);
    }
    ...
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    }
    ...
}

 class TargetViewChangeListener extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        int[] currentLocation = new int[2];
        mDrawDataPojo.getWalkthroughMetaPojo().getTargetView().getView().getLocationOnScreen(currentLocation);
        if (currentLocation[0] != mOriginalLocationOnScreen[0] || currentLocation[1] != mOriginalLocationOnScreen[1]) {
            final boolean isActionBar = ABUtils.isActionBarActivity(getActivity());
            final int containerId;
            try {
                mDrawDataPojo.getWalkthroughMetaPojo().setTargetView(new SpotlightTargetView(getActivity(), mDrawDataPojo.getWalkthroughMetaPojo().getTargetView().getView()));
                containerId = AndroidUtils.getContainerId(getActivity(), isActionBar);
                ABPromotionFragment abPromotionFragment = ABPromotionFragment.newInstance(mDrawDataPojo.getViewDataPojo(), null, mDrawDataPojo.getWalkthroughMetaPojo());
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, abPromotionFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ABLogger.d("TargetViewChangeListener - TimerTask - exception: " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer.